# Is it possible to pass selenium control to already open Browser

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium with python client. I want to run my scripts again from where it left.

For Example, Suppose i am running my script and due to some exception my script stops but i have removed selenium.stop command so that my browser remain open, now i have fixed the problem due to which exception occurred, now i want to run remaining script in the existing browser from where it left.

I heard about selenium session that i can restore session id and than reuse it but don't know how to proceed in order to pass selenium handle to that browser.

If anybody have some thoughts than let me know.

Comment: I have resolved it today itself. I have stored selenium session Id and than used it in another run!!!!